# r how to get total count of repeated values

Tags: r, loops, count

I have a dataframe with person_id, study_id columns like below:

```
 person_id    study_id    
 10            1          
 11            2          
 10            3          
 10            4          
 11            5
```

I want to get the count for number of persons (unique by person_id) with 1 study or 2 studies - so *not* those with particular value for study_id but:

- 2 persons with 1 study
- 3 persons with 2 studies
- 1 person with with 3 studies
- etc

How can I do this? I think maybe a count through loop but I wonder if there is a package that makes it easier?

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible and include expected result? There's a myriad of ways to do this.

Comment: And could you explain what a "study" is defined to be for this problem?

Comment: Roman - I would love to, but I've made the data as basic as it can possibly be, 2 columns of a few numbers. Also Expected results is below - if you have any hints or examples showing how I can improve this further please let me know.

Comment: Richard in this example persons are like academics and studies are research studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a sample data set that better matches your expected output, i'll use this

```
dd <- data.frame(
   person_id = c(10, 11, 15, 12, 10, 13, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15), 
   study_id = 1:11
)
```

Now I can count the number of people with a given number of studies with.

```
table(rowSums(with(dd, table(person_id, study_id))>0))

# 1 2 3 
# 2 3 1
```

Where the top line is the number of studies, and the bottom line it the number of people with that number of studies.

This works because

```
with(dd, table(person_id, study_id))
```

returns

```
         study_id
person_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
       10 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0  0  0
       11 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  0  0
       12 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0
       13 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0
       14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1  0
       15 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1
```

and then we use `>0` and `rowSums` to get a count of unique studies for each person. Then we use `table` again to summarize the results.

The creating the table for your data is taking up too much RAM, you can try

```
table(with(dd, tapply(study_id, person_id, function(x) length(unique(x)))))
```

which is a slightly different way to get at the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer also works although with smaller data frame, when I tried it on all my df it gave this error: "cannot allocate vector of size 4.9 Gb", strange because I didn't think it was that big.

Comment: @Kash I've added an alternate method that avoids the table. Maybe you just have a lot of unique study_ids that aren't shared or repeated. That may make the first `table()` inefficient.

Comment: Thanks again! the modification works beautifully and very fast. I was also wondering if it can be modified to show # persons with 0 studies, or # persons with 5+ studies?

Comment: @Kash how exactly would a person with 0 studies appear in your raw data? And you could cap it at 5+ by sneaking in a `pmin(5,...)` around the `with`, inside the `table`.

Comment: @Kash If you have `NA` values in study_id and want to count those as 0, just put a `na.omit` inside the `unique()` to drop all `NA` values.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can use the aggregate function to get counts per user.

Then use it again to get counts per counts

i.e. assume your data is called "test"

person_id study_id
        10        1
        11        2
        10        3
        10        4
        11        5
        12        NA

You can set your NA to be a number such as zero so they are not ignored i.e.

```
test$study_id[is.na(test$study_id)] = 0
```

Then you can run the same function but with a condition that the study_id has to be greater than zero

```
stg=setNames(
aggregate(
study_id~person_id,
data=test,function(x){sum(x>0)}),
c("person_id","num_studies"))
```

#### Output:

stg
  person_id num_studies
        10           3
        11           2
        12           0

#### Then do the same to get counts of counts

```
setNames(
aggregate(
person_id~num_studies,
data=stg,length),
c("num_studies","num_users"))
```

#### Output:

> > num_studies num_users
> >                0         1
> >                2         1
> >                3         1

Comment: I think this works - but it does not say how many users/persons have 0 study, and starts from 1? If you can please add some more info on how this works. Thanks again

Comment: thanks, this is good but I am confused because when I add the total number of users together, they are slightly higher than the unique(person_id), can you think how this could happen?!

Comment: hard to say without seeing your actual data! do you have duplicates in your original set>

Comment: Yes I believe so. Does your code go unique on person_id?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

tmp <- df %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  summarise(num.studies = n()) %>%
  group_by(num.studies) %>%
  summarise(num.persons = n())
```

Comment: This works surprisingly fast! thank you. Do you think it can be modified to include persons with 0 studies? or all those with 5+ studies? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
> dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "person_id    study_id    
   10            1          
   11            2          
   10            3          
   10            4          
   11            5
   12            6")
```

I think you can just use `xtabs` for this.  I may have misunderstood the question, but it seems like that's what you want.

```
> table(xtabs(dat))
# 10 11 12
#  3  2  1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df <- data.frame(
  person_id = c(10,11,10,10,11,11,11),
  study_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,5,1))
# remove replicated rows
df <- unique(df)

# number of studies each person has been in:
summary(as.factor(df$person_id))
#10 11 
# 3  4 

# number of people in each study
summary(as.factor(df$study_id))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: doesn't this do what was required?

Comment: thanks, looks like an interesting attempt but unfortunately I am not sure what the produced factor as it looks like a matrix of numbers and not ordered. I did not down vote by the way.